# Why does a PRE element with newlines do not produce blank lines in the output?

Tags: html, newline, whitespace, w3c

#### Example 1

```css
pre {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>
foo
</code>
</pre>
```

Blank lines appear above and below `foo`. This is expected because there are newlines in the PRE element.

#### Example 2

```css
pre {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<pre><code>
foo
</code></pre>
```

A blank line appears above `foo` but not below it. Why?

#### Example 3

```css
pre {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<pre><code>foo</code></pre>
```

There are no blank lines before or after `foo` anymore because there is no newline in the HTML code.

#### Example 4

```css
pre {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>foo</code>
</pre>
```

There are newlines after `<pre>` and before `</pre>`. So I was expecting blank lines before and after `foo` in the output. Why are there no blank lines in this example?

#### Question

1. Why only one blank line appears in example 2?
2. Why are there no blank lines in the output of example 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example 1 has similarities to example 4. I'll come back to this...

Examples 2 and 3 are the basic cases. In example 2, ignoring the `code` tags, you have the `pre` start tag, a new line character that creates the blank line, "foo", a new line character that ends that line and then immediately the `pre` end tag. Note that a single space before the  end tag is sufficient to create a blank line under the "foo" line.

Example 3 contains no new lines at all. But `pre` is, by default, a block level element so "foo" appears on a line of its own anyway. Nothing more to say about this.

Example 4 is like example 2 except that the code tags have moved lines. This exposes a particular oddity of the HTML parser. [The HTML parsing algorithm says](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#the-in-body-insertion-mode):

> **↪ A start tag whose tag name is one of: "pre", "listing"**
>
> If the stack of open elements has a p element in button scope, then close a p element.
>
> Insert an HTML element for the token.
>
> **If the next token is a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character token, then ignore that token and move on to the next one. (Newlines at the start
>   of pre blocks are ignored as an authoring convenience.)**
>
> Set the frameset-ok flag to "not ok".

So the initial new line character, which immediate follows the `pre` start tag, gets dropped on the floor and there is no blank line before the "foo" line. Whereas in Example 2 the `code` start tag is the token which immediately follows the `pre` start tag, causing the new line character which follows that to not be ignored.

Example 1 is likewise. The initial new line following the `pre` start tag is ignored, the new line following the 'code`start tag creates a blank line, then the foo line and its new line character, then the new line following the 'code` end tag creates a blank line below the "foo" line, and them the `pre` element ends.